# Folder redirection in the cake php3

Tags: cakephp

I am new in cakephp3. Can anyone tell me how we use redirection in the cake php 3. My concept is this if user login then it's redirect to the dashboard controller which is in Backend folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're most likely looking for the 'prefix' attribute
Example:

```
return $this->redirect([
    'prefix'=>'backend'
    'controller' => 'Dashboards', 
    'action' => 'index'
]);
```

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#redirecting-to-other-pages